# How to unimport a file from vbscript?

Tags: syntax, vbscript

How do I unimport a file from vbscript? Because the file I imported has a lot of global variables, which coincides with the other file I want to import.

I just want to import 1 file at a time in order to prevent overlapping of global variables. How do I achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data made available to a current script context MUST be unique. If you use '**ExecuteGlobal** *statement*' in the main context, routine or function then all data is available globally. Use '**Execute** *statement*' to make data available in a current context.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342311f1(VS.85).aspx